# How do you view all connections generated by a web page?

Tags: java, firefox-addon, filtering, web-deployment, network-traffic

Short of using Wireshark to view all traffic when you visit a website, does anyone know of a Mozilla add-on that can be used to see all the IPs a webpage is calling out to?

I'm trying to find what IP is being blocked inside this website that heavily uses java to generate it's UI. Most of it works, but something inside of it is not connecting out when being accessed via our corporate network.

Comment: Developer Tools?

Comment: I'm sorry. Do you mind clarifying?